# .NET Core 6 URL Redirect virtual path

Tags: url-rewriting, asp.net-core-6.0, url-rewrite-module

I'm working in a .NET Core 6 application with the URL Rewrite module and trying to get the proper rule for what I think is a simple query the redirect doesn't seem to be happening.  I have a rewrite-rules.xml file I initialize in my middleware and that's working without issue as the other 19 rules I have in place work.  This is the one I'm having issues with:

```
<rule name="Redirect old blog path to root" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^blog-page/(.*)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

What's wrong with my rule that it doesn't work?  I want to redirect everything from `domain.com/blog-page/*` (with any extension, .html, .aspx, .pdf, etc) to `domain.com/blog` with no relative url path (because all urls changed).

Answer (score 0):

I had a test in my side with your rule.

Firstly, I had a BlogController which would `return Ok("this result from Blog controller");` when visiting `localhost:port/blog`, and I have `wwwroot/blog-page/myhtml.html`. This should match your scenario.

Then I use your url rewrite rule in my app, which makes me get the home page when I hit `http://localhost:port/blog-page/myhtml.html`.

What we had in the rule means it would redirect to the `/` route when the incoming request matches the regx. If we require to redirect to `domain.com/blog`, we might change to `<action type="Redirect" url="/blog" redirectType="Permanent" />`.

Comment: By the way, at first I used your rule which would redirect to `/`, after I changed to use `/blog` instead, it doesn't take effort in my browser, and I test in another browser, it worked. I'm not sure what did you mean about `doesn't work`. Pls kindly correct me if I misunderstood your issue.

Comment: Ideally I want to redirect everything from `/blog-page` to `/blog`.  I'll make that change and report back with any updates.